# Germany Layover Covid Restrictions

Tags: transit, germany, layovers, covid-19

I'm an Indian citizen and an F-1 OPT visa holder. I need to travel from US to India due to unavoidable personal reasons. I am transitting through Frankfurt with a layover of 3 hours, booked as a single ticket through Luftansa. Is there any travel guidelines (like registering in a website or Covid test and such) that I should be aware of for this layover?

Comment: Is this a single ticket ?

Comment: Yes, it is a single ticket booked Luftansa. I have updated the description to reflect this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.